# Getting a stable frame rate from Android

Tags: android, camera, preview

I'm trying to get a stable frame rate from a simple camera Android application written based on the guide below.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html - Non intent version.
There is only preview and there is no image or video capture. Everytime onPreview (implementating previewcallback) is called, I check timestamp differences to measure frame rate. Though on average it meets the 15 FPS rate I set ( setPreviewFpsRange(15000, 15000 and verified that it is supported on the device using getSupportedPreviewFpsRange() ), the individual frame rate vary from 5 fps to 40 fps.

Is there a way to fix this. What are the reasons for it? Guess one reason is application process priority. It was observed that adding more applications reduced the fps. One solution is to increase priority of this camera application. Second reason could be garbage collection and slow buffer copies to preview. Third reason is that camera api (not the new camera2 api of Android L - my device is not supported yet) was not designed for streaming camera data.

Also the exposure time lock was enabled to fix frame rates.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely just how you are timestamping the frames. Try saving a sequence of preview frames pointed at a stopwatch to disk and viewing them using a YUV player (i.e http://www.yuvtoolkit.com/).